# functional if else on a Boolean

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm looking to do a very basic if else on a boolean optional value.  I'm missing something very basic I think

so the old school if else nest is like this

```
    if (filterValue.isPresent()) {
        if (filterValue.get()==true) {
            method1();
        } else {
            method2();
        }
    } else {
        method3();
    }
```

I've tried various attempts at 2 replacements

```
filterValue.map(o -> o.TRUE ? method1() : method2()).orElse(method3());
```

and

```
filterValue.isPresent(filterValue.get().TRUE ? method1() : method2());
```

and can't quite seem to get the syntax ?

Could anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Besides the problem of using `void` methods in an expression, what’s the purpose of accessing the `TRUE` constant through you condition? That’s as if you had written `Boolean.TRUE` which renders the entire expression to the left of `.TRUE` useless.

Comment: just invert your first condition and make a series of `if else` - best you can get IMHO

Comment: Yes fair point Holger.  Sorry I rushed out the question as I was getting frustrated at not finding the syntax I wanted.  There are a few mistakes in there tbh as focusing elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` doesn't work, because neither `method1` nor `method2` have a return value. And mapping to `void` is not allowed.

Currently there is no real neat solution in Java 8, but if you happen to use Java 9 you achieve it with `ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<T>, Runnable>)`:

```
filterValue.ifPresentOrElse(value -> {
    if(value){
        method1();
    } else {
        method2();
    }
}, () -> method3());
```

Comment: I find this solution perfectly acceptable. I don’t know in what way one should want something “neater”.

Comment: @Ole well it's just not available below java 9, that's why I mentioned the "neat"

Comment: Java 9 appears better than Java 8 to handle Optional flows but it is still cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

This maps the `Optional` to the returned value of the methods :

```
filterValue.map(o -> o.TRUE ? method1() : method2()).orElse(method3());
```

It is not what you want and besides it will compile only if the methods return something and compatible between them.

While this cannot compile as `isPresent()` doesn't accept any parameter but return a `boolean` :

```
filterValue.isPresent(filterValue.get().TRUE ? method1() : method2());
```

---

The old school way is the way for your requirement.
`Optional` was introduced to prevent `NullPointerException`.
And in some specific cases as you want to map the `Optional` to another thing it will spare conditional statements :  `Foo foo = Optional.map(..).map(...).get();`.
But you are not in this configuration : you want to invoke a distinct method according to 3 distinct states of the `Optional` : present and true, present and false, absent.
`Optional` don't provide direct methods to perform such a logic.

---

Your code could be more readable by reducing the nesting level :

```
if (filterValue.isPresent() && filterValue.get()) {
    method1();
} else if (filterValue.isPresent()) {
    method2();
} else {
    method3();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though, this is not really the way you use Optionals, you could try it this way:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Optional<Boolean> filterValue = Optional.of(true);
    // final Optional<Boolean> filterValue = Optional.of(false);
    // final Optional<Boolean> filterValue = Optional.empty(); // thx @Holger

    Runnable methodToCall = filterValue
        .map(b -> b ? (Runnable) Test::method1 : (Runnable) Test::method2)
        .orElse(Test::method3);

    methodToCall.run();
  }

  private static void method1() {
    System.out.println("Method1");
  }

  private static void method2() {
    System.out.println("Method2");
  }

  private static void method3() {
    System.out.println("Method3");
  }
}
```

Comment: When using a type hint, it can be done without casts: `filterValue.<Runnable>map(b -> b ? Test::method1 : Test::method2).orElse(Test::method3)`

Comment: @Lino or move the cast out of the branches: `.map(b -> (Runnable)(b? Test::method1: Test::method2))`

Comment: Instead of `Optional.ofNullable(null)` you can use `Optional.empty()`…

Comment: @Holger does work too, but I prefer not to use casts. But let everyone decide for themselfs

Comment: @Lino good idea with the type hint, but might look a little confusing. Depends on one's code style I guess?

Comment: @Holger Cast outside of the branches does not work for me. I get a compile error `method reference not expected here` (using javac 1.8.0_162)